# C# - How to convert List<Dog> to List<Animal>, when Dog is a subclass of Animal?

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

I have a class `Animal`, and its subclass `Dog`.
I have a `List<Animal>` and I want to add the contents of some `List<Dog>` to the `List<Animal>`.
Is there a better way to do so, than just cast the `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`, and then use `AddRange`?

Answer (score 17):

You don't need the cast if you're using C#4:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();

animals.AddRange(dogs);
```

That's allowed, because `AddRange()` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

If you don't have C#4, though, then you would have to iterate the `List<Dog>` and cast each item, since covariance was only added then. You can accomplish this via the `.Cast<T>` extension method:

```
animals.AddRange(dogs.Cast<Animal>());
```

If you don't even have C#3.5, then you'll have to do the casting manually.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to post - you can't cast, but you can use the covariant AddRange() to "convert" between list types. It's not perfect but it does the job.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this depends on which version of .Net you're using. I could be mistaken, but in .Net 4 I think you can do

```
animalList.AddRange(dogList);
```

Otherwise in .Net 3.5, you can do

```
animalList.AddRange(dogList.Select(x => (Animal)x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Cast<T> ()`

```
//You must have using System.Linq;

List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog> ();
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal> ();
animals.AddRange (dogs.Cast<Animal> ());
```

EDIT : As dlev points out, if you run framework 4 you don't need to cast.