# Casting a list of concrete objects to abstract types

Tags: java

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java), but the solution is showing a warning saying "Unchecked cast". Is there a safer way to do this. Code is given below.

```
public abstract class Animal {
.
..
public class Dog extends Animal{

..
    public Vector<Animal> myFunc(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Vector<Dog> arVector = new Vector<Dog>();
        return  (Vector<Animal>)(List<?>) arVector; 

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA: Casting List<Animal> to List<Dog>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999364/java-casting-listanimal-to-listdog). See also: [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not safe because:

```
Vector<Dog> dogVector = new Vector<Dog>();
Vector<Animal> animalVector = (Vector<Animal>)(List<?>) dogVector;
animalVector.add(new Animal()); // seems to be ok, but...
Dog dog = dogVector.get(0); // Runtime exception - there's Animal, not Dog in your Vector.
```

There is a reason why compiler won't allow you casting types with different generic types. You can bypass this restriction, but this will probably lead to serious problems in the runtime (*ClassCastException*s).

EDIT:

The problem is that you have to return a Vector with Animals, but you create Vector of Dogs or Cats depending on some conditions. What you can do is:

```
public Vector<? extends Animal> myFunc(String[] args) {
   Vector<Dog> vector = new Vector<Dog>();
   // ...
   return vector;
}
```

or:

```
public Vector<Animal> myFunc(String[] args) {
   Vector<Animal> vector = new Vector<Animal>();
   vector.add(new Dog());
   return vector;
}
```

Comment: @learningtocode I don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve. Obviously casting Vector<Dog> to Vector<Animal> is a bad idea, but you didn't explain why do you need such cast.

Comment: I have a method that needs to return list of animals. The method creates list of dogs or cats depending upon some inputs, the solution in the links suggests using wild card, but it seems to be unsafe. so is there a safer solution?

Comment: You can return Vector<? extends Animal>, or you can create Vector<Animal> and add to it Dogs or Cats.

Comment: That seemed to work, I did not know you could add dogs and cats to list of animals. I am surplussed that compiler thinks that is safe :) Thanks again!

Comment: It is safe, because you can retrieve only Animals from this list, not Dogs or Cats. Of course they are (in fact) Dogs or Cats, but their type (known to compiler) is Animal, so you can do only Animal things with them - unless you explicitly cast them down to Dogs or Cats. PS. You can accept this answer if it's helpful :)

Comment: @Grzegorz Olszewski Done :)